# Adding a fedora repository and including the gpgkey (dnf)

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, dnf

i have a Linux system where dnf packet manager is installed but no package sources are enabled.
So i created a directory "/etc/yum.repos.d" in this directory i have the files fedora.repo, fedora-updates.repo and fedora-updates-testing.repo.
However whenever i try to do dnf -update -v i get the following error message:

`DNF version: 1.1.9 Cannot download 'https://packages.grafana.com/oss/rpm': Cannot download repomd.xml: Curl error (77): Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) for https://packages.grafana.com/oss/rpm/repodata/repomd.xml [error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none]. Cannot download 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f$releasever&arch=i386': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f$releasever&arch=i386 [SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate]. Fehler: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'`

I think the error is due to the non existant gpgkey-files. In the .repo file there is the following line: `gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-releasever-$basearch`
But this directory doesn't exist in my system.
So my question is, where or how do I get those gpgkey-files?